# How to display of the elements one by one with angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to know how to deal with angular to display an element at a time when clicking a button .
The items are hidden by default and when there is no longer of elements the button is hidden.

**FIRST STEP**

div one ----> always display

div two ----> hidden

div three----> hidden

button ---> **click**

**SECOND STEP**

div one ----> always display

div two ----> **visible**

div three----> hidden

button ---> **click**

**THIRD STEP**

div one ----> always display

div two ----> **visible**

div three----> **visible**

button ---> **click**-->hidden

This is my exemple : http://plnkr.co/edit/PKx3pqrSwvyzhprBN8jI
But the example the two hidden items appear on the first click

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div><input type="text" placeholder="first input"></div>
  <div ng-show="state.show"><input type="text" placeholder="second input"></div>
  <div ng-show="state.show"><input type="text" placeholder="third input"></div>
  <button ng-click="state.show=!state.show">Add input</button>
</body>
```

Thank you in advance for all your answers that could help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by maintaining a counter:

```
$scope.show = 0;
$scope.incrementState = function () {
  $scope.show++;
}
```

and then in the HTML:

```
<div ng-show="show >= 1"><input type="text" placeholder="second input"></div>
<div ng-show="show >= 2"><input type="text" placeholder="third input"></div>
```

If you only need two inputs this may be best for what you need, but if you want the number of inputs to be flexible you could use `ng-repeat`

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <div ng-repeat="input in main.inputs track by $index">
    <input type="text" placeholder="first input">
  </div>

  <button ng-click="main.inputs.push('another')">Add input</button>
```

And in the controller: `this.inputs = ["first"]`

Comment: Thanks @Explosion Pills for you reply.